# Scraping a website that requires multiple requests to access a specific table (connected drop down menus)

Tags: python, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape data from this website https://pigeon-ndb.com/races/. At first, I thought the problem would be easy to solve if I figured out how to select elements from a drop-down menu, but it's ending up being more complicated than anticipated.

I ideally want to iterate through all the years & seasons (2010-2019) and then through all the records of all the organizations and the races. In summary, scrape the data from all the tables located in the website using scrapy (no selenium).

I know that the problem involves utilizing the GET requests for the drop-down menus (3 total) like so:

1. https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_databases (somehow select the json elements for year and season for the next request)
2. https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_organizations&database=2010%20OB&_=1557098607652 (requires the year and season from the previous request to work)
3. https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_races&organization=&_=1557098607653 (requires the name of the organization from the previous request (#2) to work)

The following code is a basic outline of the scrapy spider I plan to use, subject to change:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class PigeonSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pigeonspider'
    allowed_domains = ['pigeon-ndb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pigeon-ndb.com/races/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
    def parse2(self,response):
        pass
    def parse3(self,response):
        pass
```

Since it's a GET request, I'm expecting to use this multiple times (or some variation):

```
yield Request(url,callback=self.parse2)
```

I think I'll need to incorporate json for the dynamic parts of the scraping process, but not sure if it's the best approach

In scrapy shell:

```
import json
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body)
```

This is the json output for the first request ( https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_databases):

`{'data': [{'year': '2010', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2010', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2011', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2011', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2012', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2012', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2013', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2013', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2014', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2014', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2015', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2015', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2016', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2016', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2017', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2017', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2018', 'season': 'OB'}, {'year': '2018', 'season': 'YB'}, {'year': '2019', 'season': 'OB'}], 'jsonapi': {'version': 2.2, 'db': 'pigeon-ndb'}, 'meta': {'copyright': 'Copyright 2019 Craig Vander Galien', 'authors': ['Craig Vander Galien']}}`

I'm still learning scrapy so would appreciate example code on how to approach this problem. Thanks!

**Edit:**

So I tried implementing the following code but I'm running into errors:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
import json


class PigeonSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pigeonspider'
    allowed_domains = ['pigeon-ndb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pigeon-ndb.com/races/']

    def parse(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for node in result['data']:
            yield Request(
                url = 'https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_organizations&database={year}%20{season}'.format(year=node["year"], season=node["season"]),
                callback = self.parse_organizations,
                cookies = {'database':'{year} {season}'.format(year=node['year'],season=node['season'])},
                meta = {
                'year': node['year'],
                'season': node['season'],
                }
            )
    def parse_organizations(self,response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for node in result['data']:
            org_num = node['orgNum']
            if node['orgNum'] is None:
                org_num = 'null'

            yield Request(
                url='https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_races&organization={org_name}&orgNum={org_num}'.format(org_name=node["Sys"], org_num=org_num),
                callback=self.parse_races,
                headers={'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                cookies={'database':'{year} {season}'.format(year=response.meta["year"], season=response.meta["season"])}
            )
    def parse_races(self,response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)
        for node in result['clockings']['data']:
            yield {
            'race':node['racename'],
            'season':node['season'],
            'date':node['date'],
            'year':node['year'],
            'time':node['Time'],
            'complevel':node['CompLevel'],
            'class': node['class'],
            'city': node['City'],
            'zip': node['Zip'],
            'state': node['State'],
            'entry': node['entry'],
            'first_name':node['FirstName'],
            'last_name':node['LastName'],
            'line_num':node['LineNum'],
            'band_num':node['band_no'],
            'color': node['BB'],
            'sex': node['sex'],
            'arrival_time':node['arri_time'],
            'distance':node['distance'],
            'speed':node['speed'],
            'reg_points':node['reg_points'],
            'std_points':node['std_points'],
            'unirate':node['unirate'],
            'place': node['Place'],
            }
```

When running spider (error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/glenn/Projects/pigeonscraper/pigeonscraper/spiders/pigeonspider.py", line 13, in parse
    result = json.loads(response.body)
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/glenn/anaconda3/envs/scraperenv/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: If you are starting with Scrapy, I suggest you take a look at their [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). It goes step by step on how to create a new spider... Their documentation is also pretty well written and helps a lot when in doubt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set two params (`database` and `season`) using `cookies`. After that you can iterate over JSON results:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
import json


class PigeonSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pigeonspider'
    allowed_domains = ['pigeon-ndb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_databases']

    def parse(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for node in result["data"]:
            yield Request(
                url="https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_organizations&database={year}%20{season}".format(year=node["year"], season=node["season"]),
                callback=self.parse_organizations,
                # headers={'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest", 'referer': "https://pigeon-ndb.com/races/"},
                cookies={'database':'{year} {season}'.format(year=node["year"], season=node["season"])},
                meta={
                    "year": node["year"],
                    "season": node["season"],
                }
            )

        pass
    def parse_organizations(self,response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for node in result["data"]:

            org_num = node["orgNum"]
            if node["orgNum"] is None:
                org_num = "null"

            yield Request(
                url="https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_races&organization={org_name}&orgNum={org_num}".format(org_name=node["Sys"], org_num=org_num),
                callback=self.parse_races,
                headers={'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest"},
                cookies={'database':'{year} {season}'.format(year=response.meta["year"], season=response.meta["season"])}
            )

        pass
    def parse_races(self,response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for race_key in result["data"].keys():

            race_date = result["data"][race_key]["date"]
            race_release_time = result["data"][race_key]["release_time"]
            race_bird_attend = result["data"][race_key]["bird_attend"]
            # etc.
        pass
```

**Update** You're completely ignoring my comments. `parse_race_details` was not implemented in your code at all!

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
import json


class PigeonSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pigeonspider'
    allowed_domains = ['pigeon-ndb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_databases']
    debug = False

    def parse(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for node in result["data"]:
            yield Request(
                url="https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_organizations&database={year}%20{season}".format(
                    year=node["year"], season=node["season"]),
                callback=self.parse_organizations,
                # headers={'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest", 'referer': "https://pigeon-ndb.com/races/"},
                cookies={
                    'database': '{year} {season}'.format(
                        year=node["year"],
                        season=node["season"])},
                meta={
                    "year": node["year"],
                    "season": node["season"],
                },
                dont_filter=True,
            )

            # Debug
            if self.debug:
                break

        pass

    def parse_organizations(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        for node in result["data"]:

            org_num = node["orgNum"]
            if node["orgNum"] is None:
                org_num = "null"

            yield Request(
                url="https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_races&organization={org_name}&orgNum={org_num}".format(org_name=node["Sys"], org_num=org_num),
                callback=self.parse_races,
                headers={'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest"},
                cookies={'database': '{year} {season}'.format(year=response.meta["year"], season=response.meta["season"])},
                dont_filter=True,
                # meta={
                #     "year": response.meta["year"],
                #     "season": response.meta["season"],
                # },
            )

            # Debug
            if self.debug:
                break


        pass

    def parse_races(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        if result["response"] == "failed":
            print("Failed response!")

        for race_key in result["data"].keys():
            race_name = result["data"][race_key]["racename"]
            race_date = result["data"][race_key]["date"].replace("/", "%2F")
            race_time = result["data"][race_key]["Time"]
            yield Request(
                url="https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_race_details&racename={race_name}&date={race_date}&time={race_time}".format(race_name=race_name, race_date=race_date, race_time=race_time),
                callback=self.parse_race_details,
                headers={'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest"},
                # cookies={'database': '{year} {season}'.format(year=response.meta["year"], season=response.meta["season"])},
                dont_filter=True,
            )

            # Debug
            if self.debug:
                break

        pass

    def parse_race_details(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body)

        if result["response"] == "failed":
            print("Failed response!")

        for node in result['data']['clockings']['data']:
            yield {
            'race':node['racename'],
            'season':node['season'],
            'date':node['date'],
            'year':node['year'],
            'time':node['Time'],
            'complevel':node['CompLevel'],
            'class': node['Class'],
            'city': node['City'],
            'zip': node['Zip'],
            'state': node['State'],
            'entry': node['entry'],
            'first_name':node['FirstName'],
            'last_name':node['LastName'],
            'line_num':node['LineNum'],
            'band_num':node['band_no'],
            'color': node['BB'],
            'sex': node['sex'],
            'arrival_time':node['arri_time'],
            'distance':node['distance'],
            'speed':node['speed'],
            'reg_points':node['reg_points'],
            'std_points':node['std_points'],
            'unirate':node['unirate'],
            'place': node['Place'],
            }

        pass
```

Comment: I'm seeing this error when I try to access the table data (parse_races) via the jsonapi: 

`'clockings': {'response': 'failed', 'message': "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND racename...`

Comment: Are you sure you're running my code? Just checked on ALL years / seasons and ALL organizations without any error...

Comment: Were you able to access the json data in the "clockings" race_key when parsing the individual races?

Comment: As you can see I didn't implement `parse_race_details` in my code. But it's as simple as a `GET` request to `https://pigeon-ndb.com/api/?request=get_race_details&racename=NORTHERN%20CA%20CLASSIC&date=10%2F16%2F2010&time=1287541677`

Comment: Yes I saw that, my issue isn't that I'm not able to get the json (I get most of the info fine), it's just one key in the json that is 'failing'. It also happens to be the one with the information I need (["data"]["clockings"]). Could you check if you can access the "clockings" key on your end? I might not be running your code correctly.

Comment: As I said I have no code for this part. Please show your code and I'll explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I understand what you were trying to say now. Thanks so much for your help and patience.